# How do you filter an object of objects with unique keys in an angular ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I am trying to figure out how to fintler an object of objects in a angular ng-repeat.

**Data**

```
$scope.data = {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3};
$scope.filterStr = 'ey';
```

**NG-Repeat**

```
<div ng-repeat="(val, key) in data | filter:filterStr"></div>
```

This obviously does not work as the filter is expecting an array and not an object but I want to know how to do this without converting my data to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to create a custom filter.  The below code works great.

**Custom Filter**

```
angular.module('ui.global')
.filter('objFilter', function () {
  return function (obj, param) {
    var newObj = {};
    if(param){
      for(var key in obj){
        if(key.toLowerCase().includes(param.toLowerCase())){
          newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
      }
    } else {
      newObj = obj;
    }
    return newObj;
  };
});
```

**Data**

```
$scope.data = {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3};
$scope.filterStr = 'ey';
```

**NG-Repeat**

```
<div ng-repeat="(val, key) in data | objFilter:filterStr"></div>
```